# Twitter Bootstrap 3 - 3 even columns on 765

Tags: responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using Twitter BS3 for the first time and I am trying to achieve 3 equal columns on all viewports larger than 320px wide (iPhone, lets say). On a viewport of 320 and less I want my columns to stack vertically.

Looking at the grid system in the docs, I can see that I can set the flow of the grid system by using the following classes

Max container width None (auto) 728px       940px   1170px
Class prefix            .col-           .col-sm-    .col-lg-

The problem with the above seems to be that you can only control the layout of the columns on anything above 728 pixels. But what if I want 3 equal columns side by side on anything above 320 and not their predefined 728 pixels?

A good example of what I am looking for can be found on the Jetstrap homepage.
The three blue circles retain the side by side layout until you are on a 320 px wide viewport.
My version of this starts to stack vertically at around 728 pixels.

Comment: I played around with your problem and I see what you are getting at. I think you're going to have to add in a media query for 320px breakpoint to a custom responsive style sheet. I guess the Bootstrap logic is that anything under 728px should be handled in the same manner. So you have to add in a custom media query to control the styles between 320 and 728. col-# will control anything under 320 for you col-sm-# is 728 to 940 and col-lg-# is anything above 940

Answer (score 0):

You could use a @media query to override how Bootstrap normally handles the "tiny" grid `.col-4`..

3 columns HTML..

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-4"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-4"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-4"></div>
</div>
```

CSS media query for less than 320px to change `.col-4` to 100% width..

```
@media (max-width: 320px) {
  .col-4 {
    width:100%;
  }
}
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/73952

Comment: Thanks Skelly and Matt for the help. I notice BS 3 RC2 was released just this morning and addresses this specific issue so I'll try that first. Appreciate your help though.

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commit/a2b9988eb908e5b95fb253aac7fde0fbd61c375e